# Replace an entire word based on pattern using SED

Tags: linux, regex, sed

I have a bunch of virtual machines that I deploy over and over again in a large automated test environment. Each VM, after it gets deployed, writes its hostname to `/etc/hosts`.

```
127.0.0.1     XXXX-testbot-XXX
```

When it gets deployed, I want to replace **"xxxx-testbot-xxxx"** with **"yyyy-testbot-yyyy"**.

In fact, depending on the deployment, the hostname can even be **DDDD-SSSS-EEE-testbot-XYXXY"**

I'm looking for something as find word with "testbot" and replace with new value

I tried this:

```
x="garn13-testbot-15"
sudo sed -i "s/\*\(testbot)*\).*/$x/g" /etc/hosts
```

But this would just replace the match of "testbot" itself:

```
Before:
127.0.1.1       garn13-testbot-12

After:
127.0.1.1       garn13-garn13-testbot-15
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is to look for the delimiter(s):

```
sed "s/[^ \t]*testbot[^ \t]*/$X/g"
```

This relies on the greediness of the matching algorithm and allows for a trailing white with either space or tab as a delimiter.